# OpenCV: Speeding up detection of simple shapes on iPhone

Tags: c++, iphone, performance, opencv

I am trying to detect shapes with 6 corners using OpenCV on iPhone(videostream). I am getting quite good results but for the cost of a low frame rate which is around 8 fps (depending on the detecting contours)
Following some code snippets and the corresponding frame rate (if I would break after this call) and some time measurements using the OpenCV getTickCount() and getTickFrequenzy();

```
clock_t now;
clock_t then;
double tickpersecond = cv::getTickFrequency();
double elapsed_seconds;
// around 24 fps

then = cv::getTickCount();
GaussianBlur( gray, gray, cv::Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );  // 20fps
Canny( gray, gray, m_threshold, m_threshold * 2,3 ); // 13fps
now = cv::getTickCount();
elapsed_seconds = (double)(now - then) / tickpersecond;
// elapsed_seconds is around 0.068183 seconds

//assuming we there are around 120 contours found
cv::findContours( gray, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1,   cv::Point(0,0) ); 
// 10 fps and elapsed_time around 0.008560 seconds
```

I am not sure if there is something to speed up but I find it a bit strange that there is a drop of 3fps when i run findContours but with a quite low elapsed_time of 0.008560. However the biggest part is following code snippet:

```
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ) 
{
    cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
    std::vector<cv::Point> output;
    approxPolyDP( contours[i], output, 0.01*arcLength(contours[i],true), true );
    convexHull( output, convexContour );
  if(convecContour.size() == 6)
  //dosomething which I think is not performance relevant
  }
  //8 fps and elapsed_time == 0.018076
```

I am dealing with a contours.size() from 10 - 150. 
I really hope that you guys can point out some things where I can improve the performance to a constant frame rate of 15.

Comment: Both `GaussianBlur` and `Canny` are relatively slow if done on the CPU. You might check out [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage), which would speed up those operations considerably.

Comment: thank you for the hint. However I am using the framework from http://computer-vision-talks.com/ which already supports GPU acceleration.

Comment: Have you actually implemented code with GPU acceleration on the iPhone? I was under the impression that OpenCV only supported CUDA.

Comment: Tbh I am using OpenGL ES to draw the images but I am not running any OpenCV algorithms like Canny using GPU acceleration. This might something I will have to look into. But apart from that I was wondering if there are other ways to accelerate the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Problems are these flags: CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_L1

try using: CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE

your used [flags](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) are trying to find full hierarchy of nested contours.